# Filter issue in Offline Synch for Azure Mobile Services inside Android Studio

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services, offline-mode

We try to implement Offline `Synch` for Azure Mobile Services inside Android Studio.
I followed this article to achieve this.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-offline-data/

There is step 9 which explains how to get table record from offline SQLlite database table but not filter option.  I can get the complete table records, do ORDER BY on table and get top few records but cannot set a WHERE kind of clause to get selected few records. How to extend below  expression to get filtered results from `mPullQuery`?

```
final MobileServiceList<ToDoItem> result = mToDoTable.read(mPullQuery).get();
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

The MobileServiceList<> is an instance of ArrayList<>, which is fairly easy to filter.  Check out the following post for a quick example on filtering ArrayList<> in Java: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/521466/Filtering-a-List-in-java

The Android Java implementation is generally JDK7 compatible, with limitations.  That means you can use whatever ArrayList filtering mechanism you like.  Unfortunately, you can't use the newer JDK8 predicate based filtering.

Comment: Thanks for response but I need to use WHERE kind of statement to filter from offline SQLlite database. This is a different approach but will not work for a large amount of data where I want to filter specific record by a record id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the pull query. The tutorial you mentioned does that in the beginning of step 4.

```
mPullQuery = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class).where().field("complete").eq(false);
```